# Google Cloud Quota GPUS For Free Trial and I upgrade acchount

Tags: google-cloud-platform

[enter image description here][1]

Hi How to Fix that
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qrpO.png

Comment: The image in your questions explains your problem and solution. Stack Overflow cannot help you with this issue. You must contact Google Cloud.

Answer (score 0):

It says here on free trial it is not available:

```
You can't add GPUs to your VM instances.
```

[Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier)

So fix is to upgrade your account.